# xdvipdfmx shows out of memory problem

Tags: texlive, memory, xdvipdfmx

I am running a file contain 800+ pages nearly 300 Images, when compile the file in `TeXlive/xelatex`, it shows the error "`xdvipdfmx:fatal: Out of memory - asked for 21624001 bytes`"

same file compiling without error, when using the argument `-no-pdf`

how to increase the memory in the xdvipdfmx or xelatex, to compile the whole file without error.

Comment: you might get better error message if you use `--no-pdf` and then run xdvipdfmx on the xdv file. Can you re-sample the images to be smaller?

Comment: @ David Carlisle , I already tried, the same way with --no-pdf and try to make pdf xdvipdfmx, but same error exists

Comment: yes I'd expect you get same error but maybe you can use `-vv` or another option to get a more useful message out of it